# local database connectivity error in android(api19) application using xampp server

Tags: php, android, json, android-logcat, localserver

i am new to android. i am building an android application that connects with local server. 
the server used is xampp 3.2.1.
i have used json parser to do the crud operation on database.
i have defined the json parser class.

when i start my main activity i get following errors(here is my logcat for mainactivity):

```
11-02 17:47:46.236: E/IMGSRV(16540): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 43
11-02 17:47:46.236: E/IMGSRV(16540): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
11-02 17:48:07.356: E/IMGSRV(16540): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 43
11-02 17:48:07.356: E/IMGSRV(16540): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 49
11-02 17:48:07.396: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
11-02 17:48:07.396: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
11-02 17:48:07.406: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
11-02 17:48:07.406: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
11-02 17:48:07.406: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 15
11-02 17:48:07.406: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 16
11-02 17:48:07.406: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 17
11-02 17:48:07.406: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 18
11-02 17:48:07.416: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 19
11-02 17:48:07.416: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 20
11-02 17:48:07.416: I/dalvikvm(16540): Total arena pages for JIT: 21
```

on going to signUp activity, after registering the user fields it says unfortunately your app has stopped. here is the logcat error for the signup activity.

```
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/JSON Parser(16540): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:126)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:1)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-02 17:51:34.176: E/AndroidRuntime(16540):    ... 4 more
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540): Activity com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21c67e98 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{21c67e98 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:371)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(SignUpActivity.java:93)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:73)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4401)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18184)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-02 17:51:34.676: E/WindowManager(16540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my laptop and mobile are both on the same network. i am connecting to my local server with laptop's ip address.

here is my jsonparser class:
    package com.example.ddubusmarg;

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        //while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          //  sb.append(line + "\n");
        //}

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        if(line.startsWith("{"))
        sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

here is signupActivity.java:
       package com.example.ddubusmarg;

```
 public class SignUpActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputId;
EditText inputPassword;
EditText inputCity;
EditText inputPhoneNumber;
// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.6/registrationjson/insertnew.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        //spinner creation
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.boarding_city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // name
    inputId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2); //id
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); //password
    //inputCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.spinner);  boarding city
    inputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); // phone number

    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */

    //again spinner 


    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String id = inputId.getText().toString();
        String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String city = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String phoneNumber = inputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", phoneNumber));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "GET", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }  

}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {

    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}


}
```

here is insertnewrecord.php:

```
     <?php

  /*
   * Following code will create a new product row
   * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
   */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

  // check for required fields
if (isset($_GET['NAME']) && isset($_GET['ID']) && isset($_GET['PASSWORD']) && isset($_GET['CITY']) && isset($_GET['PHONE NUMBER']) ) {

$name = $_GET['NAME'];
$id = $_GET['ID'];
$password = $_GET['PASSWORD'];
$city = $_GET['CITY'];
$phone_number = $_GET['PHONE_NUMBER'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO registration(name, id, password, city, phone_number) VALUES('$name', '$id', '$password', '$city', '$phone_number')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "record successfuly inserted";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

kindly help.

Comment: did you check the ip in mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

Can only speculate without seeing your code. The immediate issue you have is the `NullPointerException`, I would start off by looking at SignUpActivity.java line 126 as shown in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.example.ddubusmarg.SignUpActivity$CreateNewProduct.doInBackground(SignUpActivity.java:126)
```

Comment: in the given line, i am logging down the json object which call the makeHttpRequest method on the given json object. and i also have uploaded the code.